# Start Date and End Date in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, date, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap DatePicker. I want to Validate **From Date** and **To Date** . Start Date correctly Pick todays date.I have a Problem " To Date does not Pick the start date(ie. from date value)" .How to solve it?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fromDate').datepicker({
        startDate: new Date(),
    });

    $('#toDate').datepicker({
        startDate: $('#fromDate').val(),
    });
 });
```

Comment: Can you tell us Whats your Problem exactly ?

Comment: To Date does not Pick the start date(ie. from date value)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the time you set `$('#toDate').datepicker()` , the value of `$('#fromDate')` is empty.

You should set default `startDate` and `endDate` variables at the begining and add **[`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate)** event listener to your datepickers.

Eg.:

```
// set default dates
var start = new Date();
// set end date to max one year period:
var end = new Date(new Date().setYear(start.getFullYear()+1));

$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    startDate : start,
    endDate   : end
// update "toDate" defaults whenever "fromDate" changes
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    // set the "toDate" start to not be later than "fromDate" ends:
    $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date($(this).val()));
}); 

$('#toDate').datepicker({
    startDate : start,
    endDate   : end
// update "fromDate" defaults whenever "toDate" changes
}).on('changeDate', function(){
    // set the "fromDate" end to not be later than "toDate" starts:
    $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: Working with default format but not working with custom format, can any one suggest solution

Comment: There's one problem with this, if you erase the box contents, the old limits remain. You also need to capture the Text Box Erase scenario.

Answer (score 2):

if user clicks on fromDate first set enddate for toDate and if user clicks on toDate first we have to set start date for fromDate.

we have to also provide date format if needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#fromDate").datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
       autoclose: true,
   }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
       var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
       $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
   });

   $("#toDate").datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
       autoclose: true,
   }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
           var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
           $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="fromDate">
<input type="text" id="toDate">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In edit mode. If we set fromDate and toDate like below
        $('#fromDate').val("03-01-2023");
        $('#toDate').val("24-01-2023");
validation is not working for this. Kindly help to fix this