# Bootstrap Datepicker prevent date format changing + end date later than start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but having much difficulty preventing client from selecting an end date that is prior to the start date + vice versa (start date is after end date). I have tried a few [script changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381303/start-date-and-end-date-in-bootstrap) with no luck.

Wish the [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) had some better examples. It seems common that a date range should exclude this wrong selection ability.

I would also like to populate the start date when the end date is selected first. It is working but changes the desired formatting from dd mm yyy to mm dd yyyy.
Be nice if it also inserted selected end date - 1 year into start date.

[Made a CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/JMxpww)

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

  //INPUTS
  let startDateInput = $('#date-picker-container input[name="start"]');
  let endDateInput = $('#date-picker-container input[name="end"]');

  //INPUT VALUES
  let startDateValue = startDateInput.val();
  let endDateValue = endDateInput.val();


  $(startDateInput, endDateInput).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    maxViewMode: 3
  });

  $(startDateInput).datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {

      if($(endDateInput).val().length <= 0) {

        $(endDateInput).datepicker('show');
        $(endDateInput).val($(this).val()); //PLUS ONE DAY FROM SELECTED VALUE

      }

      $(this).datepicker('hide');

  });


  $(endDateInput).datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {

      if($(startDateInput).val() <= 0) {

        $(startDateInput).datepicker('show');
        $(startDateInput).val($(this).val()); //MINUS ONE YEAR FROM SELECTED VALUE

      }

      $(this).datepicker('hide');

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 is very much outdated. There were lots of breaking changes between alpha and the following betas. The most recent version is Bootstrap 4.0.0. final. It might be a good idea to update.

Comment: I'd highly recommend this plug-in. It is so easy to manipulate. http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Check this answer hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/63277340/6373156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about do something like this.

My own custom range function. You can customize it back. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.calendar_max_min = function(){

    var ths = $(this);
    var caltarget = ths.data("target");
    var calcheck = ths.data("calcheck");
    var calmin  = $(caltarget+"[data-type='min']").prop("value");
    var calmax  = $(caltarget+"[data-type='max']").prop("value");
         if(!calcheck){
           ths.attr("data-calcheck","true");
           ths.datepicker({
           format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
           startDate: calmin,
           endDate: calmax
            });
            ths.datepicker("show"); // trigger manual. because we set it after click;
         }else{
            ths.datepicker("destroy"); // destoy old format. and reformat option
            if(ths.data("type") === "min") calmin = ''; // if the click item is the min. can change value
            if(ths.data("type") === "max") calmax = ''; // if the click item is the max. can change value

           ths.attr("data-calcheck","true");
           ths.datepicker({
           format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
           startDate: calmin,
           endDate: calmax
            });
            ths.datepicker("show"); // trigger manual. because we set it after click;
         }
  };

  $(".my_calendar").on("click",$.calendar_max_min);

});
```

And this is jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/g2yohfb6/